# Could inner excel row properties could affect oledb visibility?

Tags: excel, oledb

ader doesn't show the first row of xls file, selected with select * from [sheet$].
Probably some inner excel row properties could affect oledb visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; **HDR=No;** IMEX=1;"
this property tells OLEDB to ignore the first row (it treats it as header).